# Namespace 'Reporting' does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I recently bought a windows 8 laptop and I installed Visual Studio 2012 on it. I opened a project I've been working on windows 7 visual studio 2012 and I cannot get it to work. I have added the references:

```
<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
```

And I have also changed the target framework (tried 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, and 4.5), but nothing appears to be working.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I expect the project on the Windows 7 machine worked because you had the required assemblies in the GAC, probably as a result of installing ReportViewer or SQL Reporting (SSRS) on the machine.

Things you could try;

- Looking in the GAC to confirm if the assembly already exists
- Installing ReportViewer/ReportBuilder on the Windows 8 machine
- Copying the DLLs from the Windows 7 machines GAC to the Windows 8 machine and referencing them in your project